# My Regexp doesnt work correctly, but work on the regexr website

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a problem with my regex. I dont know why, it's really strange but, I obtain some great result with console.log and not with my condition.

This is my code :

```js
    const regEx = new RegExp("((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_\`{|}~]).{"+k+"})", 'g');
    let possibilities = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        if(string.length<i+k) break;
        const s = string.slice(i, i+k);
        console.log(regEx.test(s), s)
        if(regEx.test(s)) possibilities++;
    }
    return possibilities;
```

```js
function count(n, k, string) {
    const regEx = new RegExp("((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_\`{|}~]).{"+k+"})", 'g');
    let possibilities = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        if(string.length<i+k) break;
        const s = string.slice(i, i+k);
        console.log(regEx.test(s), s)
        if(regEx.test(s)) possibilities++;
    }
    return possibilities;
}
console.log(count(30,6,"G=d:Dl:T=9NS1c$9qC%,^EdUVLnU-7"))
```

On my function, I get 0 possibilities, whereas I should receive 11. And when I count the `true` values of the consoles.log, I get 11 ...
Do you know why I've this problem, and how I can solved it ?

And, when I test all the string on regexr, it's work...

Comment: Try a regex literal `/.../g` instead of a string and `new RegExp()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing `console.log(regEx.test(s), s)` you're consuming the RegEx once and move an internal cursor or something.

You need to create the `new RegExp` inside the loop scope, so its cursor will be placed back at the begining and won't be consumed at each iterations.

Plus, you may want to store the result in a variable if you want to use it twice or more :

```js
function count(n, k, string) {
    
    let possibilities = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        const regEx = new RegExp("((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_\`{|}~]).{"+k+"})", 'g');
        if(string.length<i+k) break;
        const s = string.slice(i, i+k);
        const regexResult = regEx.test(s);
        console.log(regexResult, s)
        if(regexResult) possibilities++;
    }
    return possibilities;
}
console.log(count(30,6,"G=d:Dl:T=9NS1c$9qC%,^EdUVLnU-7"))
```

Comment: I'd be glad if someone who knows well how internal regex engine works to edit my answer and rephrase it correctly

Comment: Here is a technical explanation : RegExes are magic and sometime, you need to wait for Christmas for them to work properly